# Applying torch.all to every dimension except the first

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am calculating my accuracy like

```py
(outputs.round() == targets).all(dim=2).all(dim=1).sum().item() / outputs.shape[0]
```

with `outputs` and `targets` being of shape `NxAxB`.
`N` is the batch size.
The remaining part is the prediction/truth value, where I want to see if they are identical.

Currently I am using `.all(dim=2).all(dim=1)`.
The problem now is if I have a different model, the shapes will differ. They will be `NxA`, so my current approach doesn't work because `dim=2` is not present.

```py
(outputs.round() == targets).all(dim=1).sum().item() / outputs.shape[0]
```

, would work, but then again only for the second model.

Ideally I want to apply `.all` on everything BUT the fist dimension (batch dimension).
How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generalize to any number of dimensions, you could flatten the boolean tensor from the `dim=1` outwards using [`torch.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html), then apply [`all`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.all.html), and [`mean`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html):

```
>>> (outputs.round() == targets).flatten(1).all(1).float().mean()
```

**Note**: `torch.flatten(dim=1)` will flatten the tensor from `dim=1` to `dim=-1`.